# GitLab CI/CD cache error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having GitLab-Runner installed and running on Windows Server 2012. I am trying to cache `node_modules` folder.
I followed many examples found on internet and write this yml:

```
cache:
  key: "%CI_PROJECT_NAME%"       #Defines when to cache.
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - node_modules/

variables:
    SOLUTION: $CI_PROJECT_DIR\App.Web.sln

stages:
    - setup
    - build

setup:                                                                                      #From: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/12963
    stage: setup
    script:
        - npm install                                                                       #Install all packages

build_backend:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building backend branch '%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%' for '%SOLUTION%'."
        - dotnet restore "%SOLUTION%"
        - dotnet msbuild /p:Configuration=Release "%SOLUTION%"
    except:
        - tags

build_frontend:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building frontend branch '%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%' for '%SOLUTION%'."
        - npm run build:vendor && npm run build:webpack
    except:
        - tags
```

My `setup` stage run successfully(job is moved to build stage), but there are fatal errors and caching is never performed.
If we look in detail why it failed, path really is strange:

```
FATAL: open ..\..\..\..\..\cache\web\app\app:1\cache.zip: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
                            |     |   |    |
                           (1)   (2) (3)  (4)
                                          ??? 
(1) This is GitLab-Runner root dir
(2) GitLab group for project
(3) Project name
(4) I think this cause problems, because aap:1 is invalid dir name.
```

Full Log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.4.0 (857480b6)
  on Dexter (7cab42e4)
Using Shell executor...
Running on DEXTER...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at b0344f2 Fix
Checking out 692e0373 as 51-move-ci-cd-to-docker...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for %CI_PROJECT_NAME%:1...
FATAL: open ..\..\..\..\..\cache\web\app\app:1\cache.zip: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
Successfully extracted cache
$ npm install
....
....
added 1489 packages in 245.681s
Creating cache %CI_PROJECT_NAME%:1...
node_modules/: found 47345 matching files          
WARNING: GetFileAttributesEx ..\..\..\..\..\cache\web\app\app:1\cache.zip: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
FATAL: open ..\..\..\..\..\cache\web\app\:1\archive_428238003: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

I also try without `cache:key` but error is more or less the same:

```
FATAL: open ..\..\..\..\..\cache\web\app\default:1\cache.zip: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the directory under your `gitlab-runner` user home directory and give ownership to the entire cache directory.

In your specific case run the following commands

```
mkdir -p /home/gitlab-runner/cache/web/app/app/

sudo chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /home/gitlab-runner/cache/
```

Comment: I solved it by copying node_modules to external location. Thank you anyway. Will accept this answer, but with my current setup I can not check if your solution works.

Comment: okay. I spent almost 4 hours today with this issue, it works in my case, you can check it whenever you can.